# ¿Cómo puedo exportar datos a excel adjuntando imagen en php?

Tags: php, html, excel

El código que utilizo es este:

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"reporte.xls\"");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0"); 

<img src='ruta/a/la/imagen/jpg'/>
```

Comment: Probablemente necesites construirte el excel con librerias externas. [Aqui](http://www.codedrinks.com/3-librerias-para-trabajar-con-archivos-de-excel-en-php/) tienes algunas.

Answer (score 0):

Por ejemplo, usando la librería [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

```
<?php

$excel = new \PHPExcel();

// -- Aquí se añade la imagen --

$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Nombre del Objeto'); // Opcional
$objDrawing->setDescription('Descripción del objeto'); // Opcional
$objDrawing->setPath('Ruta absoluta o relativa al objecto'); // Preferiblemente absoluta
$objDrawing->setWidth(80);
$objDrawing->setResizeProportional(true);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($excel->getActiveSheet());

// -- Fin añadir imagen.

$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Mi idea es ver si con la configuracion que estoy usando se puede adjuntar la imagen sin necesidad de librerias. Hacer directa la conversion talcual

Comment: @manuel32rguex, supongo que te puedes basar en esta librería, ver qué hacen los métodos implicados, y generar tú mismo la funcionalidad. Puedo preguntar por qué no es una opción para ti usar esta (o cualquier otra) librería?